# poEdit do not find my placeholders' translations

Tags: javascript, localization, poedit, xgettext

I'm quite new to poEdit, and I'm successfully translating 95% of my keys in my javascript templates and files.

I use this syntax `__("key")`, mainly `<%= __("key") %>`.

**But** (there always is a but), for some reason, this key `email` in placeholder

`enter code here`<input type='text' name='*username' placeholder='<%= _*("email") %>'>

is not parsed with poEdit.

I'm using Python parser; with `__` keyword. What did I miss ?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Seemed to find a temporary solution, I used PHP parser with Python parser an got all my keys, even the ones in placeholders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike @Vaclav said below, I finally did not rely on xgettext (and its language validation) and made my own parser (just a parser) in PHP.

Here is the open source project, if it could help some of you https://github.com/Wisembly/jsgettext

Best

Answer (score 1):

You say yourself that you use the `__` (double underscore) keyword. `_` (single underscore) used in your other example is a different identifier, so of course it isn’t found.

As a side note, lying to the tools (be it Poedit or `xgettext`) about the language (as you do, this is no Python) is bound to cause… interesting… things sooner or later.

Comment: hi @vaclav, the above formatting is missleading. There is a double underscore for the second example. This is just not found it seems because already in a string. Like I said in my comment, adding PHP parser to Python parser (to parse *.js and *.html) solved my problem. But could not explain why ;)